# Can I read from keyboard N distinct geometric forms based on the same interface but different classes?

Tags: java

Define an interface call GeometricForm and which contains methods which return the area and perimeter of the
geometric form. Implement the interface for: squares, rectangles, circles, equilateral triangles and isosceles triangles.
Read from the keyboard N distinct geometric forms specified by their type and specific parameters (for example for a
circle, you would need to read its radius). Compute the total area and perimeter of all the geometric forms, taking into
account the fact that they do not overlap

Okay so I dont understand. Can I read from keyboard N distinct geometric forms like Rectangle, Circle, Square etc? Just declare an interface with n elements but this 5 can  circle/square/rectangle?

```
interface GeometricForm {
    double getArea();
    double getPerimeter();
    String getGeometricForm();
}
class Square implements GeometricForm{
    double l;
    Square(){
        l=1;
    }
    Square(double l){
        this.l=l;
    }
    double getL() {
        return l;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return (getL()*getL());
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return(getL()*4);
    }
    public String getGeometricForm() {
        return "Square";
    }
}
class Rectangle implements GeometricForm{
    double L, l;
    Rectangle(){
        L=1;
        l=1;
    }
    Rectangle(double L, double l){
        this.L=L;
        this.l=l;
    }
    double getL() {
        return L;
    }
    double getl() {
        return l;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return (getL())*(getl());
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*(getL()+getl());
    }
    public String getGeometricForm() {
        return "Rectangle";
    }
}
class Circle implements GeometricForm{
    double radius;
    Circle(){
        radius=1;
    }
    Circle(double radius){
        this.radius=radius;
    }
    double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }
    public double getArea() {
        return ((getRadius())*(getRadius())*(Math.PI));
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*Math.PI*getRadius();
    }
    public String getGeometricForm() {
        return "Circle";
    }

}


public class P5 {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=keyboard.nextInt();


    }

}
```

Comment: *Can I read from keyboard N distinct geometric forms like Rectangle, Circle, Square etc?* yes, but you'll need to write the code to do it. For example, you could read lines, that you would parse. Such a line could be `circle 5`, which would mean "a circle with a radius of 5", or `rectangle 10 4`, which would mean "a rectangle with a width of 10 and a height of 4`.

Comment: Thats what I thought about, something like this

Comment: `int n=keyboard.nextInt();
  int s=0,r=0;
  int choose;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
   System.out.println("1.Square");
   System.out.println("2.Rectangle");
   System.out.println("3.Circle");
   System.out.println("4.Equilteral triangle");
   System.out.println("5.Isoscel triangle");
   do {
    choose=keyboard.nextInt();
   }while(choose<1 && choose >5);
   if(choose == 1) {
    Square 
   }
  }`

Comment: What's your question then? If it is " how to create a Square", then the answer is `new Square(length)`.

Comment: can I do this in a different way? Like instantiate an interface GeometricForm with n elements and than use the methods to create different shapes?

Comment: No. You can't instantiate an interface, by definition. Only concrete classes (that implement the interface) can be instantiated. And the interface GeometricForm doesn't allow creating shapes anyway. It allows getting the area, the perimeter and the name of the geometric form. When you create a Square, you **are** creating a GeometricForm, since a Square **is** a GeometricForm.